# Hibernate unable to create schema automatically on Heroku postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, heroku, playframework, java-8

I have a play 2.4 hibernate postgresql application which works well locally, creates a table automatically initially. But when deployed on heroku it does not create any table though the app loaded without any errors(connected my heroku db from pgAdmin). My Configuration

**build.sbt**

```
name := "lms"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `lms` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc, cache, javaWs,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.0.1.Final",
  "net.sf.dozer" % "dozer" % "5.4.0")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+= baseDirectory(_ / "target/web/public/test")

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

**application.conf**

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret = "%APPLICATION_SECRET%"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs = "en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# application.global=Global

# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `conf/my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and conf/routes)
# application.router=my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}



db.default.jndiName = DefaultDS
jpa.default = defaultPersistenceUnit
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"
# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/),
# by providing an application-logger.xml file in the conf directory.

# Root logger:
logger.root = ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play = INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application = DEBUG


db.default.logStatements = true
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                      value="META-INF/sql/data.sql"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Procfile**

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/lms -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

Is there any more changes I have to do to create the database schema initially on heroku postgres? What could be the problem?

EDIT:

```
E:\Projects\lms\LMS>heroku buildpacks
=== leadmanagementsystem Buildpack URL
heroku/scala

E:\Projects\lms\LMS>heroku config
=== leadmanagementsystem Config Vars
DATABASE_URL: postgres://aaa:111@dasdsfsv.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfregv

E:\Projects\lms\LMS>heroku run "echo $JDBC_DATABASE_URL"
Running echo $JDBC_DATABASE_URL on leadmanagementsystem... !
 !    ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out.

I dint read [Play 2.4.x JavaJPA docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA#Deploying-Play-with-JPA) carefully.

---

Running Play in development mode while using JPA will work fine, but in order to deploy the application you will need to add this to your build.sbt file.

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

---

Adding the above line resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the flag

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

the distribution zip is created without **conf** folder and so META-INF/persistence.xml file is not included. I guess that in this case Play detects the JPA model by scanning for all DB annotations. 
If you have in **conf** folder configuration files, which are intended for editing on site, distribution package without **conf** folder is not appropriate.

To fix your DB problem without the flag **PlayKeys.externalizeResources** you should add you DB model mapping into **persistence.xml**. See the example in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452106/play-2-5-hibernate-table-is-not-mapped/38473502#38473502)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. Can you link me to some official source because I am confused here. You are saying in my case conf is not created so does it mean any changes to `appication.conf` will not work in production as conf folder is not created.

Comment: You can read in that very link you figured out (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA#Deploying-Play-with-JPA) right after a value of PlayKeys.externalizeResources . Your configuration will be embedded in jar with content same to the source, but it will be not editable. That is the reason, why I do not use such technique.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not recognize the `vendor://user:password@host:port/db` format of `$DATABASE_URL`. It requires a JDBC URL. Try changing your `db.default.url` to this:

```
db.default.url=${?JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```

For more info see [Heroku DevCenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url).

Comment: Ive tried that it dint work infact I try to echo the above variable it display nothing but heroku confiig shows the value of DATABASE_URL. Thats why I used it. Also on checking heroku logs the Herouku postgres db is connected but the table is not created.

Comment: What is the output of `$ heroku buildpacks`?

Comment: Oh sorry, on windows run `heroku run "echo $JDBC_DATABASE_URL"`  (no need to escape the `$`

Comment: updated question. Ive tried deploying to heroku with `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` but it gave same behavior as DATABASE_URL, application is up but tables not created

Comment: I think the error when checking JDBC_DATABASE_URL is a fluke. regardless, i'm not sure now. I've added another answer to try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how Hibernate+Play works, but if I were using Hibernate in a traditional Java app, I would initialize the EntityManager like this:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
  if (envName.contains("JDBC_DATABASE_URL")) {
    configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", env.get(envName));
  }
}

// provision persistence manager
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit", configOverrides);
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Perhaps Hibernate isn't picking up the `db.default.url`?

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I am having the same problem I have connected my heroku db from pgAdmin and I have added your code but still it doesnt show any tables in pgAdmin. With local db it works well. I think I am missing some configuration but couldnt find that.