# play 2.5, hibernate : table is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, playframework

I have been getting a exception below

(Exception is : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped )

It occured when this code is called.

```
TypedQuery<User> query = jpaApi.em().createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email and u.secretHash = :secretHash", User.class)
            .setParameter("email", parameter.getEmail())
            .setParameter("secretHash", hashAlgorithm.hash(parameter.getPassword()));
```

but if this project is running by "actirvator start" (develop env), this exception did not occur.

it mean ... only on Production environment i got this exception.

how can i fix it.

please help me.

thanks for your help and my project information is below

- System environment :

1) Play  : 2.5.4

2) hibernate : 5.2.1.final

- Exception Message :

  Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select u from User u where u.email = :email and u.secretHash = :secretHash]
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
      at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
      at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:152)
      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:521)
      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:623)
      ... 52 more
  Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3690)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3579)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:718)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:574)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
      at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
      ... 58 more
- persistence.xml

  ```
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="Hoth-PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
      <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
      <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" />

          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
          <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
          <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />

          <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5" />

          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

          <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
          <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
          <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  ```
- Entity Class Code

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table (name = "users")
  @Getter @Setter @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode (of = "email")
  public class User {
  @Id
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "secret_hash")
  private String secretHash;

  @Column(name = "accessed_at")
  private LocalDateTime accessedAt;

  private String gender;

  @Column(name = "birth_year")
  private Integer birthYear;

  @Column(name = "picture_name")
  private String pictureName;

  @Column(name = "picture_url")
  private String pictureUrl;

  private String nickname;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The User mapping is missing in the persistence.xml. I cannot see from the snippets in what package the User is defined, but let's suppose it is in the package persistence.models. The persistence.xml should be like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="Hoth-PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
<class>persistence.models.User</class>
<properties>
    ...
</properties>
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I had the mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml, but not in persistence.xml. Should it only be in persistence.xml?

Comment: I am glad it works. You should put the mapping only into persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a bug introduced in Play 2.4. You need to add the following line to your build.sbt as a workaround.

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

It appears to be related to how classes are loaded while in prod mode.

[See here for more info](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4590#issuecomment-108409625)