# ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443 Error for heroku create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

My steps are below:

1. Download the `heroku-osx.pkg`, and installed it.
2. `$ heroku login` with my account and password
3. cloned the ruby-getting-started: `$ git clone https://github.com/heroku/ruby-getting-started.git`
4. But when I run `$ heroku create` in my Terminal.

Reports the error:

> Creating app... !
>    ▸    ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443

I have find the related question in SO:

- [I got error while using "git push heroku master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189780/i-got-error-while-using-git-push-heroku-master)
- [Hibernate unable to create schema automatically on Heroku postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195729/hibernate-unable-to-create-schema-automatically-on-heroku-postgres)

But they are not when execute `$ heroku create` comes out the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Carelessly, I don't know why, I tried several times of :

```
$ heroku create
```

It create succeed, with the logs:

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ still-harbor-32209    
https://still-harbor-32209.herokuapp.com/ |    
https://git.heroku.com/still-harbor-32209.git
```

So, I think try several times will solve it.

Comment: Did the same for me when trying to run `heroku run console`. Didn't work the first time but it worked the second time. Seems random.

Answer (score 20):

The same was happening to me on Mac OS X 10.12.6 in iTerm2 3.1.5

Restarting iTerm solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

It means that the connection between `api.heroku.com` with a port of `443` and to your PC failed and results to shutdown. Thus retrying the command will succeeds.

Answer (score 6):

You may not be connected to the internet. Make sure to check your connection as it is required to complete this command.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when **the internet temporarily cut out** for a few seconds while I was trying to run a heroku command.

The Heroku CLI returned `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com`

As soon as the internet connection was restored, everything was back to normal

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue recently. 
To debug this:

1) I tried restarting my terminal entirely `CMD+Q`, but still hit the timeout issue

2) I ran a `whois` on `my-heroku-app.com` and that command also timed out, even though I could connect to it through my browser

3) I disconnected my VPN and ran a `whois` command. This fixed the issue

After reconnecting my VPN, everything worked smoothly. Not sure what caused the hiccup, but I hope these steps help for anyone trying to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. my OS is windows, I solve this problem by restarting my command line and running the command all over and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was network connection, by checking and re-establishing connection, it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same , Because I was connected to VPN  and I think network was blocking the same . So disconnect VPN and try once.